# how do i save private ip space using NAT

Tags: private-vlan

im using VLSM to assign private ip address networks to my specific vlans. Unfortunately there is not enough space in my /24 mask even when segmented in order to accommodate my user requirements for each individual vlan. How do I use NAT to save space for my vlan 3 users?

vlan 1 : 75 users
vlan 2: 45 users
vlan 3: 44 users
vlan 4 : 13 users

Comment: In addition to the general subnetting Q&A, there's no need to restrict yourself to a /24 address space. RFC 1918 allows for a lot more.

Comment: I get that but this is for an assignment and I do not have the slightest clue how to solve the problem given the constraint.

Comment: Sorry, but all educational, certification and homework is off-topic here. Reread the linked question, it's all there.